# Adding standalone zookeeper servers into fabric ensemble

Tags: apache-zookeeper, fuseesb

We're attempting to add standalone zookeeper servers into the zk ensemble ran by fuse fabric (as either followers or observers).  However, it looks like fabric has pretty tight control over the zk configuration and I haven't been able to find any documentation relating to adding hardcoded server configuration params to the dynamic ones used by fabric.  Anyone else try this or have some idea of where to look?

Comment: This is being discussed elsewhere at this forum: https://community.jboss.org/thread/224085

Comment: Yeah, I started the thread over there too.  Thanks for the heads up though.